# Expression Blend 4 Assets Behaviors not listed

Tags: wpf-4.0, expression-blend-4

I have blend 4 installed and whenever I create a WPF 4 project and go to the Assets / Behaviors, I have only one behavior listed which is InvokeCommandAction.

Where are the others like GoToStateAction...

This was working like a week ago. I tried to uninstall and re-install Blend 4 but still having the same issue !

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally found the way to solve my issue.

I had to uninstall Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) for .NET 4 then to re-install it and know I see again in blend 4 all the behaviors !